# MapBox data quality issues in certain geographies

Tags: mapbox

Not getting much luck tracking this down through their official support channels.

Does MapBox have known data quality issues in certain geographies.

Take for example the following address in Hong Kong

> 12 Cloud View Road, Hong Kong

[Google Maps has no problem finding this location by this address](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Mega+Co-op+Building+Society,+12+Cloud+View+Rd,+Hong+Kong/@22.2857083,114.19272,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x3404010103c20399:0x6abab2d0c05d3e98!8m2!3d22.2857034!4d114.1949087)
Mapbox on the other hand, does not find it. See: https://docs.mapbox.com/search-playground/#

I've tried numerous things including specifying the Country/WorldView filtering options, but still no joy. And I can't find anything in the mapbox documentaiton that talks about coverage of various nations or address languages.

I need to make a decision on whether to go with Google Maps (significantly more expensive for our needs) vs. MapBox (doesn't seem to support what we require in certain territories).